# why can't I see my facebook canvas page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I've created a new app that will be accessed via a canvas page on facebook. I've entered the required domain and url, but I'm not seeing anyplace on facebook where I can actually see the canvas page. I'm in sandbox mode, does that make a difference? I'm just not seeing any option to see my canvas page. When I go to "preview" under "Review Status" I see some kind of stand in page but not my canvas page. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apps on Facebook are loaded into the Canvas section of the Canvas
>   Page. **The Canvas is quite literally a blank canvas within Facebook on
>   which to run your app.** You populate the Canvas by providing a Canvas
>   URL that contains the HTML, JavaScript and CSS that make up your app.
>   When a person using your app requests the Canvas Page, we load the
>   Canvas URL within an iframe on that page. This results in your app
>   being displayed within the standard Facebook chrome.

**Here's how it works:**

User goes to your **canvas page** (apps.facebook.com/canvasname) and they will see the normal Facebook application interface with a sidebar on the right and the other usual elements. The application will be loaded in an iframe. **This iframe is loaded from the location you specify as Canvas URL.** Canvas URL can be a page in your own website.

See [Facebook Developers documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) for a detailed explanation.

I hope it helps!

Comment: but why can't I see my own canvas page within the facebook Chrome. Where on facebook can I navigate to my canvas page

Comment: @Spilot: `yoursite.com/canvasPageURL`

Comment: @AmalMurali when i put my url in canvas URL and Secure Canvas URL it can't open the web page. can you help to solve this problem.???