# WHERE IS THE CANVAS PAGE WITHIN FACEBOOK?

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, interface, facebook-canvas

I can't fathom why this isn't more explicit and self explanatory. What am I missing. I JUST want to see my canvas page inside the Facebook chrome. The details are set up the way they're supposed to be in the settings. Where do I go to see the page inside of facebook. Where is the link to that?

Comment: Web preview is just some template with colors and stuff. Where is the BLANK canvas page inside facebook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why can't I see my facebook canvas page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332866/why-cant-i-see-my-facebook-canvas-page)